# Change format of generated "noinspection" comments in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA 2016.2, when you suppress an inspection for a statement, the generated comment looks like this:

```
//noinspection InspectionName
```

It annoys me that there's no space before `noinspection`.  Can this template be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this comment text is built programmatically and cannot be changed by the user.